# Must provide typeDefs when using makeAugmentedSchema

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, graphql

I'm new to Neo4j and GraphQL and more or less new to JavaScript.
I want to build a GraphQL endpoint using ApolloServer and Neo4j.

**The error I don't understand is in line 9 here in server.js**

```
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
const {makeAugmentedSchema} = require('neo4j-graphql-js');

const app = express();
console.log(typeDefs);
const schema = makeAugmentedSchema(typeDefs); // here!
const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:11004", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password"));

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: {driver},
  schema,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true
});

const port = 4001;
const path = "/graphql";

server.applyMiddleware({app, path});

app.listen({port, path}, () => {
  console.log(`GraphQL server ready at http://localhost:${port}${path}`);
});
```

The error is 'Must provide typeDefs')

The ./schema file looks like the following:

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Movie {
        genres: String
        movieId: Int!
        title: String
    }

    type User {
        userId: Int!
        username: String
    }

    type Query {
        movie(movieId: Int!): Movie,
        user(userId: Int!): User
    }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

If you could give me a tip what's going on that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, the `gql` in `schema.js` is not necessary. That fixes the problem.

Comment: This answer is unclear. I'm having the same issue, but removing `gql` doesn't seem to fix it.